# HTACCESS Don't Redirect With Parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I got this line of code:

```
RewriteRule artistprofile.php rewrite.php?$1 [R=301,L]
```

But the redirection does not work accordingly,

**http://domain.com/artistprofile.php?displayname=bryan+wong** is redirected to **http://domain.com/rewrite.php?/**

I am expecting
http://domain.com?displayname=bryan+wong

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa), like this:

```
RewriteRule artistprofile.php rewrite.php [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Now, the URL `http://domain.com/artistprofile.php?displayname=bryan+wong` will be redirected to `http://domain.com/rewrite.php?displayname=bryan+wong`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't catch the query first to use $1
try this

```
RedirectMatch /artistprofile.php?displayname=(.*)$ rewrite.php?displayname=$1
```